# MVC5 where is user database

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am very new to .NET. I have created a simple MVC5 project with Individual User Authentication and I was wondering where is the database storing user info, is there any way i could access it?

Answer (score 2):

**short answer**

take a look @ connection string @ web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication8-20150118012921.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication8-20150118012921;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

it save on |DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication8-20150118012921.mdf , [your-project-path]\App_Data folder . You can view it using visual studio built in server explorer feature / management studio.

**long answer**

you should read http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started and more  guides like this to dive in and learn.